# Details about "Hide Extensions of Known file types" from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, file-extension

What does "known file types" actually mean?

[image: Windows Explorer - Folder Options]

What makes a file type "known"?

Can I explicitly add or remove extensions/types from the list of "known" file types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Known" is loosely used there.  It is saying that there are globally known file types, such as  exe, zip, cpp, txt, etc.  And then there aren't (like .blah).  That being said, the registry still shows a .blah (just unassociated with a program) - so all it's saying is show .* or not.

Of course, you can change or edit those in the Registry (warning, you can do a lot in there that is bad for your machine, so proceed with caution).  The Microsoft Development Network has a [good summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of what/why/how/etc.

Comment: There is an easier way than a registry change to change or add "known" file types as noted by @Nicole Hamilton

Answer (score 7):

Known file types are those for which you have a default application that knows how to open that type.  If that application has an icon, that's the icon you'll see for that file.  For example, it knows that it should use Word to open a `.doc` file and that's icon you would see.  But if it's a extension it doesn't recognize, that would be one that's not known.

When you install a new application, it usually registers itself as the default application for the types of files it knows about unless you already have something else associated.  That's usual way that new types get added to list of known file types.

The other way to add to the list is to create a new association manually by right-clicking on a file of that type, then choosing "Open with...", then "Choose default program..."

You'll always see the unknown file type extensions.  But this option trims off the ones like `.doc` that it knows about.  It's totally a matter of personal taste which you prefer.

Comment: Nice answer!  Very complete